# How to calculate the number of weeks between two dates in hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

How to calculate the number of weeks between two dates in hive ?  I need a better approach.. As of now I am calculating by `datediff` function. is this the correct approach ?

```
datediff(String EndDate, String StartDate) / 7
```

Comment: i think this good way ,you can use weekofyear diff but that will work for same year data

Comment: *"I need a better approach"*.  Why?  What is wrong with this one?